# Java architecture for server with latency sensitive outgoing connections

Tags: java, multithreading, scalability, mina

For a game project I'm building something that has some challenges in scalability that seem reverse from how you would normally scale a webapp. In short I have a webserver that receives requests, which are naturally executed in parallel by the threadpool for the appserver (Jetty). So far the easy part.

For each request the server needs to call a large (e.g. 500 - 1000) number of participants (running their own simple webapps) concurrently, gather their moves and combine them to a result to answer the initial incoming request. The participants are simple webapps written by untrusted programmers participating in the game. They may be too slow or unreachable or actively try to break things by responding slowly.

Appservers are generally designed to handle the incoming requests cleanly using a ThreadPool. But how would you go about the outgoing requests part? I thought about launching Threads (or use a ThreadPool) to make the callout to each of the participants, then in those threads use HttpClient from Apache httpcomponents to set strict timeouts (e.g. "must respond within 500ms") and have the main request thread wait for all of them to finish. Possibly using a ConnectionManager and keep-alive to ensure the threads return as fast as possible (if the participant isn't stalling which most probably won't be doing)

But for just 20 concurrent incoming requests and 500 participants that would launch 10000 threads (or block on the ThreadPool if it is smaller than that) which is not a good idea.

I have been unable to find common solutions, most things I find are written around scaling the server-side of things (looked at Apache Mina for example) while in this case I'm basically acting as a very high volume latency sensitive client.

So are there common approaches to this? Maybe (open source) programs that do something similar that I could analyze? Libraries using NIO for handling large amounts of outgoing requests? Or libraries that are designed around this?

Comment: The service you describe is more like a proxy-service: both server-like and client-like. It would be simpler if the client making the request contacts the participants directly (possibly after receiving a list of participants from your server) and gathers the results. Is that not possible?

Comment: Take a look at [Netty](http://netty.io/) and [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). You want to use an evented approach, not a request-response threaded model (especially not classic http with a teardown after each request). There are many libraries depending on the stack you want to adopt, like [Comsat](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/comsat/), so the choice is implementation-wise after you have the architectural details figured out.